# dynamically load user controls using jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, dynamic-usercontrols

I've read several articles on this issue, and technically speaking, all they end up doing is taking html code from a user control and injecting it into the containing page.  I want a true user control to be loaded on to the page, so that on postback, I still have access to that loaded user control and I can validate fields on it on server side, etc. etc.  What I mean to say is that once the user control has been loaded onto the page using ajax, it should there after act like it was originally created as part of page life cycle when the page was first loaded.  Does that make sense?  Any ideas on how to do this? UpdatePanel may be a solution, but I'd rather not use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update panel is the solution since you need it to update the page's ViewState so that the newly added usercontrol needs to be part of the page lifecycle.  Also, when the page does post back, you need to remember that it was added and re-add it so that the control structure gets re-created properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically create user controls, you have to make sure to bind to the elements.  Look into http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live